CMake / QNX 6.5 does not understand gnu99 standard
I have already been made aware of this question, in which the OP seeks to use C++11 standards.
And I understand that - regrettably - C++11 is just too new for QNX 6.5.
But my question relates to the same compiler and the C99 standard, which is approximately 10 years older than the compiler being used here.
I am converting an existing QNX 6.5 project to CMake. This builds fine(ish) in Momentics, but I am falling at the first hurdle; generating the project.
I have this as my CMake file
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

project(Analyser)

# other stuff

When I try to generate this using the QNX toolchain I get
The C compiler

    "/opt/qnx650/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/user/build.analyser/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_4ee62 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ee62.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ee62.dir/testCCompiler.c.o 
    /opt/qnx650/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmle -Wc,-isysroot,/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6   -std=gnu99 -Wp,-MD,CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ee62.dir/testCCompiler.c.o.d -Wp,-MT,CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ee62.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -Wp,-MF,CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ee62.dir/testCCompiler.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ee62.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /home/user/build.analyser/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    cc: unknown option: -std=gnu99

If I remove the CMAKE_C_STANDARD then the project generates fine, but it does not build because it defaults to C89 I guess.
If I bypass the compiler check (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS) then of course the project generates fine.
But building the code gets me this...
/opt/qnx650/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmle -Wc,-isysroot,/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6  -I{lots of include dirs} -Wc -std=gnu99 -Wp,-MD,syslib/CMakeFiles/syslib.dir/logger.c.o.d -Wp,-MT,syslib/CMakeFiles/syslib.dir/logger.c.o -Wp,-MF,syslib/CMakeFiles/syslib.dir/logger.c.o.d -o syslib/CMakeFiles/syslib.dir/logger.c.o -c /home/user/project/syslib/logger.c
cc: unknown option: -std=gnu99

(not sure why so many options get repeated)
So the cmake compiler check wasn't just a hinderance.
The thing is, this works from within Momentics
/opt/qnx650/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/qcc -Vgcc_ntoarm -c -O -Wc,-Wall -pedantic-errors -Wc,-std=gnu99 -DNDEBUG -I{lots of include dirs} -EL -DVARIANT_a -DVARIANT_le -DBUILDENV_qss /home/user/project/syslib/logger.c 

I doubt that the other command line options make any difference here for making the compiler understand gnu99  (I've not looked into these yet, but I will), but if you know better then please put me right.
The question comes down to this:
What must I do to use the c99 / gnu99 standard in a QNX 6.5 CMake project?

"qcc --help" shopuld give you the accepted options. After some searches on the WEB, I didn't see any "std" option accepted by qcc

Hi, so what is your question? Yes, these are the facts, yes, the compiler doesn't understand gnu99, yes, cmake fails. So what now? Do you want to use other option with the compiler or something? It is unclera to me what exactly are you asking.

@KamilCuk the compiler does understand gnu99. The Momentics output proves this.

I think I have worked it out but I need to refine the process. It is all in the command line arguments. I need to "prefix" compiler options intended for gcc through "-Wc" when invoking qcc. How to make that work for CMake? I don't know yet.

This document from Blackberry / QNX 6.5 on the qcc compiler interface explains that qcc does not understand the -std argument.
The document suggests we pass certain options to the (cc1) compiler thusly
-W phase,arg[,arg ...]
    Pass the specified option and its arguments through to a specific phase:

        p — preprocessor
        c — compiler
        l — linker
        a — assembler.

So to compile for C99 we should invoke qcc as
qcc -Wc,-std=c99 {other parameters} [source file]

CMake cannot do this for you when you add set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99) to your QNX 6.5 based project.
One possible workaround I am working with does...
if (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION GREATER 4.4.2)
    set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
else()
    add_compile_options(
        $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:-Wc,-std=gnu99>
    )
endif()

Please note that these instructions apply to QNX 6.5 only!
As of QNX 7, the -std argument is supported by qcc and you should be able to nominate the C standard in the way CMake intended without any of this "fuss".

Keep in mind that qcc is not the actual compiler but a "compiler interface", much like gcc. Both qcc and gcc use a compiler named cc1 for compiling C code. For more information, see this SE question.
